# How to implement Exact-match Evaluation in NER

Tags: python, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I am following this [article](https://valueml.com/named-entity-recognition-using-lstm-in-keras/) to make a NER system using BiLSTM and CRF layers. But for the evaluation of the final model, I want to implement an “exact-match evaluation” for precision, recall and F1 scores to check if the model can correctly identify an entity and its associated boundary as well.
I need guidance as to how can I modify the solution given in this article so that I can implement an 'exact-match evaluation' system

Comment: That article said they have 98% accuracy! and How would it know if it's wrong when it thinks that it's right?

Answer (score 0):

I request you to run all these in a jupyter notebook then
Try this tfma metric, this may work out

```
tfma.metrics.ExactMatch(
        name: str = EXACT_MATCH_NAME, convert_to: Optional[str] = None
    )
```

name: The name of the metric to use
convert_to  The conversion to perform before checking equality.
refer to this link for further details
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/ExactMatch